# Swift Button acts like a sensor when finger passes on

Tags: ios, swift, button, touch, sensors

I'm trying to make an app something like this but i couldn't find out how to do it. i have tried many things but it didn't work or i couldn't make it work since i'm very new on swift.
this is the video reference: https://youtu.be/6cCV_YsbUq0?t=2s

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure , but you can try with x and y position of screen touched, to find x and y position follow this code.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self.view)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```